# 2D Array in While loop bounds

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having some issues with figuring out how to work with a 2D array and a while loop.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
while (
    table[i - count][j] === 0 ||
    table[i + count][j] === 0 ||
    table[i][j - count] === 0 ||
    table[i][j + count] === 0
) { ... count++; }
```

I get the following error when running my snippet:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Now I understand that this is happening because if I have `i = 0` then `table[i - count][j]` would been it is checking `table[-1][j]`. Obviously this shouldn't work but that is the purpose of the while loop that I've implemented.

I want the code to stop running when either the edge of this 2D array is out of bounds (like explained above) or if the element's value is 0.

Currently it gives me the error when I just need it to stop and carry on with the code after the while loop. How do I solve this?

**EDIT:**

Yeah I'm sure I want these conditions to be `&&`. The main issue is that `i -count` could result in a negative number. Or `i + count` could result in a number out of bounds for the array.

How do I deal with those out of bounds occasions in this while loop?

Comment: Should you not have `||` after every condition?

Comment: Was that the only issue? Looking at your rep, I was hoping something else would be the real problem. But its ok. We all have such moments. But as an advice, having such a long expression in while will make code less readable. Instead create a local function/variable

Comment: Ok I've edited my question appropriately

Comment: I have added a version of how I would have done. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As commented before, using I would suggest using a function that returns a boolean value. This will keep your loop clean and you can choose to have a more descriptive code for conditions.

```js
function validate(array, i, j, count){
  // To cover case when either variable is 0
  if(i && j){
    let prev = array[i - count];
    let next = array[i + count];
    let curr = array[i];

    return (
      (j < prev.length && prev[j] === 0) ||
      (j < next.length && next[j] === 0) ||

      // Since we have already added a check for value !== 0, 
      // we just have to check for out of bound here.
      (j < curr.length -1) && (
        curr[j - count] === 0 ||
        curr[j + count] === 0
      )
    )
  }
  return false;
}
while (validate(table, i, j, count)) { ... count++; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make shure the array exists before accessing its keys, and checking for 0 or undefined is irrelevant as both are *falsy* :

```
while(
 (table[i - count] || [])[j] &&
 (table[i + count] || [])[j] &&
 (table[i] || [])[j + count] &&
 (table[i] || [])[j - count]
) count++;
```

Comment: @barry michael doyle what is this code supposed to do? ( it might be much much easier)

Comment: @barry *sign in to access this page :/*

Comment: It's a little `maxProdInTable` challenge. So it actually was supposed to be `&&`...  My full algorithm makes sense, I'm just not getting the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Right I've found a solution. It's probably not optimal in general but for what I'm doing it's perfect:

```
while (
    i - count >= 0 &&
    j - count >= 0 &&
    i + count < table.length &&
    j + count < table[i].length
) {
    if (
        table[i - count][j] === 0 ||
        table[i + count][j] === 0 ||
        table[i][j - count] === 0 ||
        table[i][j + count] === 0
    ) return prod;

    prod *= (
        table[i - count][j] *
        table[i + count][j] *
        table[i][j - count] *
        table[i][j + count]
    );

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your conditions are connected by `"and"`
Just add extra conditions to check for valid values/bounds for your array index

```
while (
    table[i - count][j] !== 0 && table[i - count][j] !== undefined &&
    table[i + count][j] !== 0 && table[i + count][j] !== undefined &&
    table[i][j - count] !== 0 && table[i][j - count] !== undefined &&
    table[i][j + count] !== 0 && table[i][j + count] !== undefined &&
    i - count > 0 &&
    j - count > 0
) { ... count++; }
```

Comment: Count may still exceed the max array length

Comment: Thanks, but the `i` and `j` values are always more than 0 (according to my input)

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle
`i` and `j` may be `> 0`, but is `i - count > 0` and `j - count > 0`? 
And what's the upper limit for the values of `i + count` and `j + count`

Comment: The upper limit is the length of the 2D table array. I'm assuming that if the bounds are reached the statement would just return false and not run. Clearly I'm wrong. How can I work around this?  I want it to run while the bounds don't get reached...

Comment: The following doesn't work either:

   `while (
        table[i - count][j] !== 0 &&
        table[i + count][j] !== 0 &&
        table[i][j - count] !== 0 &&
        table[i][j + count] !== 0 &&
        (i - count) >= 0 && (j - count) >= 0 &&
        (i + count) < table.length && (j + count) < table[i].length
    )`